# Jira server plugin - set page title (browser) dynamically

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I want to set title of page (in browser tab) dynamically.

This is successfully achieved in JIRA server plugin, but not in JIRA cloud plugin. Please refer following code:

**JIRA Cloud Plugin:**

```
"generalPages": [{
    "url": "/my-general-page",
    "name": {
        "value": "Hello World"
    },
    "key": "my-general-page"
}]
```

**Output:**

[image]

**JIRA Server Plugin:**

```
<webwork1 key="mygeneralpage" name="My General Page" class="java.lang.Object" i18n-name-key="test-mymodule.name">
    <description key="test-mymodule.description">My General Page</description>
    <actions>
        <action name="com.atlassian.myplugin.action.myAction" alias="MyPage">
            <view name="createuserissue">/UI/my-page.vm</view>
        </action>
    </actions>
</webwork1>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Please guide me what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

In JIRA Server, you set the page title within your `UI/my-page.vm`. For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title Goes Here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        [...]
    </body>
</html>
```